# Regex to match unescaped pairs of braces

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently trying to make a regex to match the closest pair of an opening and closing bracket without matching escaped braces. (And without matching double escape characters infront of a non escaped bracket).

```
{"asd"} - {"asd"}
\{"test"} - No match
\\{"Apple juice}"} - {"Apple juice}"}
{{"Test"}} - {"Test"}
```

I'd already be glad to find a regex which just maches unescaped characters without using `\K`I have tried multiple things but I can't figure out why this regex doesn't work: `((?<!\\)(?=(?:\\{2})*)){`

Comment: With what language do you want to do that? Is it for a replacement?

Comment: Which of the 4 lines are considered matched? Also, what Regex engine are you using?

Comment: Since you mention `\K` - is it PCRE? Do you also want to ignore the braces inside quotes? Have a look at [`(?<!\\)\\[{}]|(\{(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\\n]*)*"|[^{}\n]*)(?:\\.(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^{}\n]*))*})`](https://regex101.com/r/wY0xG4/5).

Comment: I am seriously impressed :D It worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\\)\\[{}]|(\{(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^{}]*)(?:\\.(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^{}]*))*})
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY0xG4/6)

The regex matches 2 alternatives:

- `(?<!\\)\\[{}]` - an escaped opening or closing brace with no `\` in front

OR (this one is captured, so you can grab it by accessing the first capturing group)

- `(\{(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^{}]*)(?:\\.(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*‌​"|[^{}]*))*})` - matches and *captures into Group 1* a substring starting with

  - `\{` - opening brace
  - `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^{}]*)` - a quoted string containing any escaped sequences (`"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")` or 0 or more characters other than `{` and `}` (`[^{}]*`)
  - `(?:\\.(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*‌​"|[^{}]*))*` - matches 0 or more sequences of...

    - `\\.` - escaped sequence
    - `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*‌​"|[^{}]*)` - see description above
- `}` - closing brace